# Why Does mat-bottom-sheet-container Overflow and Not Stick to the Bottom of the Screen on Mobile Devices?

Tags: android, css, angular, angular-material

I have a popup window located within my angular app. This popup is working correctly so far, I have emulated different screen resolutions with Chrome's built-in DevTools Screencast to make sure this container has the correct styling/position on mobile devices. This all works correctly.

The whole element is a `mat-bottom-sheet-container`.

However, I have now tested this on a real tablet and noticed that this popup is cut off. Everything worked when i tested it with various different screen resolutions in DevTools though. What could be the cause of this Problem?

Thats how it looks on my android tablet running Chrome v116.0.5:

[image: screen2]

And thats how it looks in Devtools ScreenCast running Chrome v116.0.5:

[image: screen1]

The screen resolution on both screenshots are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out what was causing this problem.

The problem was that the whole document on my tablet had a scroll bar. However, it was not really visible. I had to scroll all the way down outside the `mat-bottom-sheet-container` and then open my popup to see the whole window.

I always tried to scroll down after I had already opened the popup, but this didn't work because when the window was open you couldn't scroll down. Long story short - i just needed to set the position of the popup to `position: fixed;` to resolve this issue.

Took me some time to figure it out.